# What does zip in optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_variables)) do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Why do we use zip in  `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,self.generator.trainable_variables))` ?
How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

When computing gradients using `tape.gradient()` it returns the gradient for weight and bias as list of lists.

Example:

> grads= [ [ [1,2,3] , [1] ],  [ [2,3,4] , [2] ] ] #Op from `tape.gradient()`
>
> should interpret as [ [  [W],[B]  ],  [  [W],[B]  ] ]

Consider this as trainable_weights or Initialized_weights

> trainable_weights= [ [ [2,3,4] , [0] ],  [  [1,5,6],[8]  ] ]

So Zip will take the first values of both variables and zip them for the optimizer to minimize it.

The Zipped `zip(grads,trainable_weights)` values will look like this.

> [ [1, 2, 3], [1] ], [ [2, 3, 4], [0] ]
>
> [ [2, 3, 4], [2] ], [ [1, 5, 6], [8] ]